# List manager is empty

Tags: xdb, list-manager

I have problem with list manager in Sitecore 8.2.
When I create a new list, it does not get contacts from xDB. In the segmentation list option "Use all contacts as source" is not available (grayed out).
In Experience Profile I see contacts and I can search by name or email.

Comment: Could you attach screenshot of your list where you see segmentation list option "Use all contacts as source" is not available?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/UJUIJVa.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see, you already have enabled "All contacts (Entire database)".That is why your option disabled. You need to add segmentation for your list and set condition. After that you will see your contacts.

This is standard behavior for lists.